# Clarification on use of sigma notation

Tags: notation

I find the use of sigma notation quite arbitrary. Sometimes the counters and limits are defined, sometimes they aren't. And sometimes, I just can't comprehend what it means.

For example, in my textbook, they've given an example,

$$\alpha^3 + p\alpha + q = 0$$
$$\beta^3 + p\beta + q = 0$$
$$\gamma^3 + p\gamma + q = 0$$

Now, here's the confusing part, they jump straight to saying:

$$\implies \sum \alpha^3 + p\left(\sum \alpha\right) + 3q = 0$$

which I can't make the head or tail of.

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing the context, which might make things better, I'm inclined to blame the textbook here for being confusing. However, if they wrote:

$$\alpha_1^3 + p\alpha_1 + q = 0$$
$$\alpha_2^3 + p\alpha_2 + q = 0$$
$$\alpha_3^3 + p\alpha_3 + q = 0$$

then you could conclude that:

$$\sum_{i=1}^3\alpha_i^3+p\left(\sum_{i=1}^3\alpha_i\right)+3q=0$$

which should be clear (I hope). However, in this case, I would be happy enough with:

$$\sum\alpha_i^3+p\left(\sum\alpha_i\right)+3q=0$$

as I consider it fairly obvious that the sum must be over $i$, and the range should also be clear, so I can write a slightly less cluttered expression. This is a matter of taste though, and if I thought there was a chance of confusion I would take the first option.

The book seems to be assuming it's obvious that the sum is over Greek letters, and this is not a convention I support.